# Compute log-likelihood in Bernoulli Gaussian Mixture

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-mixture-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

I'm working on this exercise about Gaussian Mixtures:

[image: Exercise]

Here's part of the solution:

[image: Solution]

I don't understand how they came up with this equation for the log-likelihood (red arrow).

From what I know, the likelihood would be computed using the joint probability of $X$ and latent variables $Z$. And then use the log to turn the product into a sum:

$p(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{m} p(X=x_{i} | Z=z_{k}) P(Z=z_{k})$

But then in the solution above, the terms $r^{(i)}$ computed in the E step are also used.

Can someone explain ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is a closing parenthesis missing in the equation after the red arrow. To solve this homework, you need write down the joint likelihood in $(x,z)$.

Comment: @Xi'an thank you for your comment, I updated my question to give more details about my problem.

Comment: When you consider $p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ you are not using the joint likelihood.